# How to use a function inside of a function using javascipt?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently attempting to build a quiz template for a teacher to fill in for their tudnts to answer questions.
I have a javascript function to display the desired amount of questions, an html div that has all the neccessary input boxes, and a javascript function to toggle this div. My problem is that i do not know how to put them together.This is what i have so far, ad i dont know why it isnt working.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

var number = prompt("Enter the number of questions");
var myHTML = '';
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  myHTML += '<span class="test">Question ' + (i + 1) +
  '</span><br/><br/>'

  <input type="button" value="Show DIV" id="bt" onclick="toggle(cont)">
}

wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML
function toggle(cont) {
      var cont = document.getElementById('cont');
      if (cont.style.display == 'block') {
          cont.style.display = 'none';

          document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show DIV';
      }
      else {
          cont.style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide DIV';
      }
  };
```

```html
<form id='namennumber' action="includes/dbquestions.php" method="post">

  <label for="quizname"><b>Quiz name</b></label>
  <input name="quizname" type="text" placeholder="Enter quizname" required>

  <div id="myHTMLWrapper">
  </div>
</form>

<div style="border:solid 1px #ddd; padding:10px; display:none;" id="cont">
  <div id="questionform" class="modal">
    <label for="question"><b>Enter a question</b></label>
    <input name="question" type="text" placeholder="Enter a question" value="question" required>
    <br>
    <label for="answer1">Possible answer A</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer1" placeholder="Enter a possible answer" value="answer1" required>
    <br>
    <label for="answer2">Possible answer B</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer2" placeholder="Enter a possible answer" value="answer2" required>
    <br>
    <label for="answer3">Possible answer C</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer3" placeholder="Enter a possible answer" value="answer3" required>
    <br>
    <label for="answer4">Possible answer D</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer4" placeholder="Enter a possible answer" value="answer4" required>
    <br>

    <h3>Correct answer</h3>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" <?php if (isset($answer) && $answer=="A" ) echo "checked"; ?> value="A" />
    <label for="A">A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" <?php if (isset($answer) && $answer=="B" ) echo "checked"; ?> value="B" />
    <label for="B">B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" <?php if (isset($answer) && $answer=="C" )echo "checked"; ?> value="C" />
    <label for="C">C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="A" <?php if (isset($answer) && $answer=="D" )echo "checked"; ?> value="D"/>
    <label for="D">D</label>
    <br>
    <button style="width:auto;" id="enter" class="btn btn-primary big-btn">Finish</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Show DIV" id="bt" onclick="toggle(cont)">` is not JavaScript code, so it throws an error

Comment: so what would i do in order to get thesame output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try add single quotes here: `onclick="toggle('cont')"`
- and remove single quotes here: `var cont = document.getElementById(cont);`

and yes, this is not js code, as [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) commented:

```
<input type="button" value="Show DIV" id="bt" onclick="toggle(cont)">
```

Use something like

```
myHTML += '<input type="button" value="Show DIV" id="bt" onclick="toggle(\'cont\')">';
```

after the loop.